# What is the difference between debug mode and normal execution on dspic?

Tags: pic

I have a dspic33fj128mc802 microcontroller. I am using mplabx and xc16 compiler. I have my internal oscillator set up to 80MHz.

I have managed to setup FreeRTOS on the device and everything compiles without errors.
I'm toggling an output pin with a 100Hz frequency. If I'm in debug mode and measure the pin with an oscilloscope I see a perfect square wave with the expected frequency of 50 Hz, High voltage is 3.313 V and low is 0V. This is in debug mode and this is what it should do.

If I let the application run on its own, without the debug, I have impulses coming at about 17 ms intervals. Each impulse lasts 3.82 microsecs with 3.313 Volts and then a very fast decrease to 0 Volts. I have absolutely no idea whats causing this. Has anybody encountered something similair before? Could this be the chip's fault or my program's fault or FreeRTOS' fault?

Comment: Without more details this is likely impossible to answer. A good place to start would be sharing your code.

Comment: I didn't share the code because it really huge as I am also running FreeRTOS with multiple includes.

Is there an option to embed code? If I just copy paste it is unreadable.

Comment: Kinda sounds like the chip is resetting over and over. Can you verify if that is happening?

Comment: I can and that is not what is happening. At least not in the debug mode. I can see the code runs constantly and executes the desired operations. Such as toggling the led or sending a character via UART.

I can only check the pins with an oscilloscope while it is running. I can't be certain if it resets when not in debug mode. Is there a way to check it?

Comment: Check the watchdog timer.

Comment: Can you show us your config bit settings at least ?

Comment: #pragma config BWRP = WRPROTECT_OFF
#pragma config BSS = NO_FLASH
#pragma config RBS = NO_RAM

#pragma config SWRP = WRPROTECT_OFF
#pragma config SSS = NO_FLASH
#pragma config RSS = NO_RAM

#pragma config GWRP = OFF
#pragma config GSS = OFF

Comment: #pragma config FNOSC = FRC
#pragma config IESO = ON

#pragma config POSCMD = NONE
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF
#pragma config IOL1WAY = ON
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECMD

#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR1281
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF

#pragma config FPWRT = PWR128
#pragma config ALTI2C = OFF
#pragma config LPOL = ON
#pragma config HPOL = ON
#pragma config PWMPIN = ON

#pragma config ICS = PGD1
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF

Comment: I have no idea how to format this :(

Answer (score 3):

The difference between production and debug mode is normally twofold.

First, the compiler does different (read: better) optimizations in production mode. For example, removing code that might not be needed, pre-calculating constants, inlining function calls, unrolling loops and so on. In debug mode such optimizations might hinder debugging, since then a line-by-line stepping through the code might not be possible (because some lines might not have corresponding machine code after compilation anymore).

Second, the libraries that are used might run different code altogether. In debug mode there might be additional log output (unlikely on a MCU though). There might be additional sanity checks, e.g. for array boundaries or integer overflows. Even the memory layout of some structs might differ.
So when you see a problem in production mode, but not in debug mode, you have encountered a [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

Since you say that your code is rather complex: can you reduce it to a minimal example that shows the behavior? Try get it down to the minimal number of tasks, then start adding them again. When you see the bug, you can limit the code area that causes that.

You can also look at the changes the debug might introduce. Disable optimization on the production build. Look at the FreeRTOS documentation what gets changed in debug mode, and try to work from there.

To check for resets: just toggle an otherwise unused pin right at the start of the program.

Comment: +1 for reducing it to a minimal program which exhibits the behavior.  Just write a simple program that toggles the same output pin and nothing else, and compare debug vs non-debug.

Comment: My program is very simple. Now it just sends one character to the UART in 5 second intervals.
The complexity is because of FreeRTOS is an embedded operating system with my .c files included. 

Someone said that the debugger also makes all the analog pins into digital. The pins I am using are not analog. But probably something like this is happenning..

Comment: After I've re read my other comment I did say my program is huge, what I meant was that FreeRTOS is huge. I don't know why I worded it in such way

Answer (score 0):

As @hli said, the optimization level may certainly be different.  One particular glitch that often confuses people is that if the compiler doesn't see any change to a variable in a routine, it may optimize around it.  Thus, get in the habit of declaring all your globals as volatile.  Give this a quick try to see if it fixes your issue.  Couldn't hurt, takes moments, right form, and might just fix the issue.

Otherwise, just try turning off optimization at compile, and see if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the helps. The code is complex because FreeRTOS is an embedded operating system which by itself uses many includes and headers. My application on the other hand is very simple. I only send one letter to the UART at 5 second intervals.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot, but the CPU clock can be set to run at different speeds when in debug mode. May be worth a quick check. In MPLAB X, go to the project properties, select your debug hardware which will be at the top of the list, then on the right hand side you'll see a pull-down menu titled 'Option Categories', select clock. There is an option to have the FRC in debug mode, and an option to set the target run-time instruction speed. I'm affraid I've no idea whether or how these settings might affect the clock speeds you've set in your code, but might be worth a quick investigation. Good luck.